# Logout Events not visible (Keycloak)

Tags: keycloak

we are using keycloak in version 1.13.0 as our Identity provider.

The backlog provides a nice overview page of the Events it received.
We configured it using this guide:

https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/events/login.html

LOGOUT events are correctly shown inside the 'Admin Events' tab but aren't shown in the 'Login Events' tab despite all events are configured inside the 'Config' tab as shown here:

[Login Events Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iZkU.png)

What do you think could be misconfigured? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas